# SQL: Query for customer sales ledger

Tags: mysql, sql

when specific user pays cash, inserts in a following table

```
payments:
description     | Amount    | Date      |   custid 
cash            | 2000      | 2014-9-24 | 5
cash            | 3000      | 2014-9-26 | 5
```

when specific user purchase product, inserts in a following table

```
orders
Product         | qty   | amount  |  date      | custid
front light     |  2    |  3000   | 2014-9-22  | 5
back light      |  2    |  2500   | 2014-9-22  | 5
```

- also guide me if above tables requires changes.?
- is any need of balance column in payments table. ?
- remember it i am a programmer not accountant if there is any mistake in debit credit let me know.

I need this result or something like this (sales ledger of a customer / customer accounts details ). what will be the SQL query ?

```
Product     | Debit  |  Credit      | Balance 
opening bal |        |              | 0
product     | 5500   |              | 5500
cash        |        | 2000         | 3500
cash        |        | 3000         | 500
```

Comment: Soo you're not interested in icluding dates in the result?

Comment: yes date's must be included and , also used in where condition. i have not written in above table to remove complexity.

Comment: I think we handle that degree of complexity. Clarity is also important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have no data for "open bal", so I am ignoring that.  It is entirely unclear where that comes from.

Getting the first three columns (with date) is a question of joining the tables together.  For this, a `union all` is the best approach:

```
select *
from ((select custid, 'product' as product, date, sum(amount) as amount, -1 as dir
       from orders
       group by custid, date, amount
      ) union all
      (select custid, description, date, 1 as dir
       from payments
      )
     ) op;
```

The next is to add the cumulative piece.  In MySQL, you would do that using variables:

```
select custid, product, date, amount,
       (@bal := if(@c = custid, @bal + amount * dir,
                   if(@c := custid, 0, 0)
                  )
       ) as bal
from ((select custid, 'product' as product, date, sum(amount) as amount, -1 as dir
       from orders
       group by custid, date, amount
      ) union all
      (select custid, description, date, amount, 1 as dir
       from payments
      )
     ) op cross join
     (select @c := -1, @bal := 0) vars
order by custid, date, dir desc
```

Comment: Also, a PK should be a serious consideration.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as dir
      
      ) 
      
      union all
      
      ( select custid, desc' at line 7

Comment: Would this work on MySQL Views? If not, can you please convert it into a form that could be created into views? I can only call table or views in my persistent class. Thanks!

Comment: @BorgyManotoy . . . If you have a question about creating a view, then ask it as a question, not in a comment.

Comment: Thanks bro, would post a question later.